# I have All in one SEO plugin, how can I remove my sitemap.xml.gz?

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, xml-sitemap

My website currently facing 2 sitemaps, one is `sitemap.xml` and the other is `sitemap.xml.gz`.

I want to remove sitemap.xml.gz from my website. How can I do that with my "All in one SEO plugin"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the all in one seo plugin is a wordpress plugin and the question is specifically about this. If it is, please tag it also with wordpress.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Is it older, out of date and created by some other tool?  Or does the all-in-one plugin create both of them?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a CMS for your website, you need to turn off the XML sitemap feature from All in One SEO plugin feature manager. And then go to your website's root Dir and delete the `sitemap.xml.gz`.